# Changing the Position of the Currency Symbol Trashes my Site

Tags: magento

For the second time now an apparently simple change manages to trash my store completely. I have given up for the moment, but if any of you has the solution I will be glad to hear it.

I have Magento 1702 (this also happened in 1700) on GoDaddy with the hellowired template and some other unrelated changes I coded in. The store is in Spain so the standard currency is the Euro and the language files (es_ES) are installed. Everything works A-Ok until I try to change the position of the € from prefix (€ 12,90) to suffix (12,90 €).

To make the change I navigate to /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/es.xml, find currencyFormat and change Â¤#,##0.00 to #,##0.00 Â¤. Simple, right?

From there on, I can't access the backend and can only access the frontend UNTIL I get to a page with a price (product or cart). When either of those happen I get a "There has been an error processing your request" screen and when I check the error logs the say "Currency USD not found". I did NOT touch the en.xml and the default currency (at admin) is the Euro.

The only solution so far is restoring the backup files. But not just the specific es.xml or even the complete es_ES folder. I have to do a full restore because I haven't been able to identify which ones actually break or why.

I can live with the € in the wrong position, but I shouldn't have to.

Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Thanks to all
Miguel

Comment: Check your error logs and report back on the specific error and Stack Overflow will be able to help you.  Despite appearances this isn't a Magento support forum, it's a programmers support forum.

Comment: Alan, thanks. I'm aware of that. I am also asking at the Magento forums but I have found the best answers here. I will post the error shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Report the specific error message here as Alan stated in his comments. But here's a thing to check if you edited this file:

- if your editor preservers the encoding of the file (utf-8)
- verify if the xml of this file is valid after saving your changes
- if your editor or ftp client preserves the file permissions on server
- verify that you have cleared the cache on the server